# How to Set onClicklistener Method of ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am Adding an array of `ImageView`s  and set an image to each `ImageView` dynamically and I'm done with it. But the problem is how to set/define onClicklistener Method on an `ImageView`?

Here is my Code:

```
ImageView[] mImages;
int[] images = {R.drawable.sandle_icon1, R.drawable.sandle_icon2,
            R.drawable.sandle_icon3, R.drawable.sandle_icon4};

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
mScrollViewImage.removeAllViews();
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
mImages = new ImageView[images.length];
mScrollViewImage.addView(ll);
for (floop = 0; floop < sandleicon.length; floop++) {
    mImages[floop] = new ImageView(this);
    mImages[floop].setImageResource(images[floop]);
    ll.addView(mImages[floop]);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hello Dipak....
u have to create integer array for ImageView...
Mitesh Jain SKP

Comment: I have Already create Integer Array.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
for (floop = 0; floop < sandleicon.length; floop++) {
    mImages[floop] = new ImageView(this);
    mImages[floop].setImageResource(images[floop]);
    mImages[floop].setId(floop);
    ll.addView(mImages[floop]);
    mImages[floop].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //v.getId() will give you the image id
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Rasel, I used that but Problem is how to get index of imageview on click of particular image.

Comment: V.getId is Give Me Only -1 Value.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in fragment

```
// update the Youtube thumbnail images
this.youtube_thumbnail = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);

this.youtube_thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("Adding youtube thumbnail");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mImages[floop].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
private OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { }
};
```

This is how you set onclicklistener to any view.

Comment: u can use mImages[floop].setTag(floop), setTag and getTag are used to store some data related to a view.

Comment: order of both statements should be changed. you should declare first and then assign the listener?