# Ontap event in android

Tags: android, tap

i have a blank screen on mainactivity.
when i tap everywhere on the screen it will do an action. such as opening a new activity or making and event. is it possible to make it on an imageview too? what is the listener that listens to the tapping and how can i get a method such as "OnTap"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know little about android but sure this can help:

create an ImageView with height and width set to match_parent

```
<ImageView

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:onClick="tap_me"

   />
```

then in your java code you can do this

```
public void tap_me(View v){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

View.onClickListener should do the work for you.

Update:

Check out similar problem: [How to Set onClicklistener Method of ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317959/how-to-set-onclicklistener-method-of-imageview-in-android)

You can only detect clicks within your app. Make the imageview to cover the entire screen. Then click on any point will be picked up by the onClickListener.

Comment: on click on screen? how can i reckonize the background?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.YourImage);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener) {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
            switch(me.getAction()) {
            case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                //do stuff here
            }
       }

    }
```