# I want to start camera, onClick event used in item of Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to start camera,  onClick event  used in item of Listview. but showing The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(). my Adapter code is here.

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem1> {

    Context context;

    public MessageListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem1> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imagep ;
        TextView name;
        TextView date1;
        TextView time;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem1 rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_message, null);
            ImageView imgcamera= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_camera);
           imgcamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.date1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Date);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
            holder.imagep = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_person);
            holder.imagecam = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_camera);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(rowItem.getName());
        holder.date1.setText(rowItem.getDate1());
        holder.imagep.setImageResource(rowItem.getImagep());
        holder.imagecam.setImageResource(rowItem.getImagecam());
        holder.time.setText(rowItem.getTime());
        return convertView;
    }    
}
```

Comment: this is a syntax error, 
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener().

Comment: got the solution from this link. thanks to PX Developer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190268/how-to-start-an-activity-by-click-of-image-button-of-a-list-view

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to move `imgcamera.setOnClickListener` outside `if` block.This callback is only running when the `convertview` is null (the first time only), but it should run each time irrespective of the value of `convertview`.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the line 
imgcamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
you have not added view.onclickListner.
For details on adding onclick listner for imageview have a look at this.
[How to Set onClicklistener Method of ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317959/how-to-set-onclicklistener-method-of-imageview-in-android)
imgcamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

Answer (score -1):

put context before startActivity `context.startActivity`